# Running steam on Alienware R12

Tags: nvidia, dell, steam

I've been trying to get Ubuntu working on a **Dell Alienware R12**, and running into various issues. I have **Nvidia-460** drivers installed, and they're picking up the **GeForce RTX 3090** okay, and Blender seems happy with that.

However, the current problem I'm looking at is that Steam crashes whenever I try to run it. I've tried both the version of steam that is in the Ubuntu repository, and also a deb I downloaded from the Steam website, and both give similar problems.

I originally installed Ubuntu 20.04, but upgraded it to **21.04** in order to get the wired network card working, so it's currently on 21.04

When I run steam, I get:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 21.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
WARNING: Using default/fallback debugger launch
/home/sam/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam
[2021-07-27 12:41:07] Startup - updater built Jul 20 2021 22:25:51
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1626824053)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  44
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2021-07-27 12:41:07] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2021-07-27 12:41:07] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2021-07-27 12:41:07] 1. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1626824053)
[2021-07-27 12:41:07] Checking for update on startup
[2021-07-27 12:41:07] Checking for available updates...
[2021-07-27 12:41:07] Downloading manifest: http://media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1626824053)
[2021-07-27 12:41:08] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1626824053, installed version 1626824053, existing pending version 0
[2021-07-27 12:41:08] Nothing to do
[2021-07-27 12:41:08] Verifying installation...
[2021-07-27 12:41:08] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2021-07-27 12:41:08] Verification complete
Loaded SDL version 2.0.15-6655637
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(steam:21570): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-2.0/main.rc:775: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'

(steam:21570): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-2.0/hacks.rc:28: error: invalid string constant "normal_entry", expected valid string constant
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Serial number of failed request:  49
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
assert_20210727124107_1.dmp[21649]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20210727124107_1.dmp
/home/sam/.steam/debian-installation/steam.sh: line 772: 21570 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER $DEBUGGER_ARGS "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
```

Following some online hints I found, I tied installing the 32bit NVidia drivers, and after that Ubuntu wouldn't start so I had to re-install.

Ubuntu takes hours to install (I'm not sure why it's so slow), so though another attempt at trying 32 bit drivers is probably in my future, are there any other suggestions? Or should I just take the risk again?

Installing 32bit drivers for Steam isn't something I've ever had to do before, so I'm not sure why it might be needed now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this myself, it was suggested that I install a slightly different 32bit driver than I'd tried before:

```
sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-460:i386
```

Installing this seems to have fixed it, and Steam is now running.